# What initializes the sender and eventArgs in raised event?

Tags: c#, events

I know how events work (the basics). I would like to understand, when e.g. there is mouse click or paint event, what initializes the PaintEventArgs argument? That is some underlying lower level mechanism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the events arguments are initialized by *the object exposing the events*.

Let's think for example to a `Button`.

When it's clicked, the button itself detects that and so invokes the event handler passing, for example, which button is pressed (fake code here, just to explain):

```
this.MouseDown(this, new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Right));
```

The same happens to the `Paint` event:
when the control detects it needs to be redrawn, creates a graphics object in which it draws its structure, then pass that to the `Paint` event through the `PaintEventArgs` argument.